# Best practice for VMWare Snapshots for lab VMs

Tags: linux, virtualization, vmware-esxi, snapshot

I am setting up test\dev machines in VMWare.  We have about six users that I would like to give a VM to.  They are all going to be based off a single base image (Ubuntu).  I could always create six different VMs, one for each user, but there seems to be a better way to do this.

Is it possible (or recommended) to install the base system, then take six different snapshots.  Since these are testing machines the users will inevitably mess them up.  Since these are uncommitted snapshots I can always just blow the snapshot away and recreate it from the base image.  I like the fact that I can quickly "restore" the user's VMs back to their default state.

The [VMWare KB](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1025279) seems to frown on long running snapshots.  Is there a better way to achive what I want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create these as separate VMs from a single master template.

This way, you can recreate the VMs as needed, but still avoid any issues associated with long-running snapshots and the performance and storage implications of doing so.

Comment: I was reading this: http://www.networkworld.com/article/2162991/cloud-computing/where-to-turn-when-vmware-stops-supporting-lab-manager-in-may.html just now because I never even knew VMWare discontinued Lab Manager.